# SQL syntax error UPDATE / WHERE

Tags: mysql

So I keep getting SQL syntax error when trying to run the following:

```
UPDATE tickets SET (ticket_urgency, ticket_status) VALUES ('Urgent', 'new') WHERE ticket_id='14'
```

Not sure what is wrong with this? I tried INSERT INTO aswell, but the tricky part here is the WHERE tiket_id='x'.

Answer (score 4):

the syntax of `UPDATE`should be like this,

```
UPDATE tickets 
SET    ticket_urgency = 'Urgent', 
       ticket_status = 'new'
WHERE  ticket_id='14'
```

- [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

for further knowledge, your query is vulnerable to `SQL Injection` if the values came from a variable, to protect from it, please read the article below

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'll read more about that. (can't upvote :P)

Answer (score 1):

your syntax is not correct please correct it

```
UPDATE tickets 
SET ticket_urgency = 'Urgent', 
    ticket_status = 'new'
 WHERE ticket_id='14'
```